# How to handle imports within imported files when they are needed only in some programs

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have one file `common_file.py` which contains functions required by other parts of my main program. At the same time, `common_file.py` imports from `only_main_required.py` some data that only uses when the main program is running. My problem is that I have another program `helper_program.py` which uses `common_file.py` but it's not located in the same directory as the main file (where the program starts, or the current directory in other words). So when I import `common_file.py`, it attempts to import `only_main_required.py` but since the current directory is different, the import fails with a `ModuleNotFoundError`.

A minimal reproducible example:

I have this project structure (super simplified but enough to reproduce what I mean):

project1

```
├── folder1
│   │
│   ├── only_main_required.py
│   
└── folder2
├    ├── common_file.py
├    └── helper_program.py
└main_file.py (origin of main program)
```

```
#only_main_required.py

random_var = False
```

```
#common_file.py

from folder1.only_main_required import random_var
```

```
#helper_program.py

import common_file
```

```
#main_file.py

from folder2 import common_file
```

So when you import `only_main_required` when running the main program, there's no problem because the main program originated in `project1` folder, so `folder1.only_main_required` makes sense and Python can find it, but when you import `only_main_required` from `helper_program`, it fails because it doesn't know of the existence of `project1` or `folder1`.

I've been looking for a while now but all the solutions I've found were for different situations (for example, a shared lib, but this is not the case here, I don't want a shared lib, I just want some code from a module that happens to import "non-importable" code when running from a specific source) and while I have possible solutions, I am still not sure on which one to choose (or if to choose another solution I am unaware of).

For example, one solution is to wrap the import from `common_file.py` in a try-except block, and in case there's a `ModuleNotFoundError`, I just pass the error since I don't need that module anyway.

Another solution is to add the path using `sys.path` in `common_file.py`, but this is the solution I like the least since it makes it harder for me to understand what is going on (with the try-except and a couple of comments, it will be clear enough that I am handling the specific case when the source is `helper_program.py` and not `main_file.py`)

And another solution is to move `helper_program` to `project1` (the root folder), but I also don't like this solution because it doesn't make any sense at all considering the overall structure of the program (`helper_program.py` is a program that helps in dealing with stuff related to the `folder2` folder).

Also, I need the imports to be in `common_file.py` and not in an if **name** guard clause because I need them when the main program is the file importing `common_file.py`, just not when `helper_program.py` is the source.

I am amazed that I wasn't able to find anything like my situation. Maybe there's another way in which these situations are usually managed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I want to expand on the comment I made in @Ted Possible's answer.

What ended up working best for my usecase is both changing the current directory AND adding the parent directory to `sys.path`, like this:

```
#helper_program.py
import os
os.chdir("../")
import sys
currentdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
parentdir = os.path.dirname(currentdir)
sys.path.insert(0, parentdir)
import common_file
```

This way, only `helper_program.py` has to change (which makes sense for my usecase since it's for developing purposes only anyway, that is, it shouldn't be included in the release version). Also, it makes sense because I have too many imports (it's a huge project) and many filepaths, so I would have to make too many changes if I went for any of the other approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Move your import into a function

Change these two files and leave everything else the same.

```
#common_file.py

def get_rand_var():
    from folder1.only_main_required import random_var
    return random_var
```

```
#main_file.py

from folder2 import common_file
rand_var = common_file.get_rand_var()
print(rand_var)
```

Comment: I like this answer for being a different solution that I hadn't thought of (strange, because I have used it before, but maybe I didn't think it would work in this context). A fourth solution and that worked best for my usecase is changing the current directory though (with `os.chdir("../")`), **plus** adding the parent directory to `sys.path`. I found that I have many many imports (it's a huge project) and I have to make too many changes (including filepaths) to make it work otherwise.